# Mapping a deleting ray to a horizontal strip

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

So, this is my question: D is a domain obtained by deleting the ray $x\leq 0$. And $G(z)$ is a branch of $log(z)$ on $D$. I want to show that G maps D onto a horizontal strip of width $2\pi$. Show that the map is 1-1.

I got that $G(z)=logz=log|z|+iargz$, then I understand that $z$ varies on $D$ from $(0,\infty)$, so $log|z|$ varies from $(-\infty, \infty)$, and $arg(z)$ varies from $(-\pi, \pi)$ by the definition from $D$. I also figured out how to explain/ prove that the map is one to one.

The only thing I do not understand and also need an explanation for myself is that why is it a width of $2\pi$? How do I explain that this is a width of $2\pi$ on the imaginary axis?

Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: It's not clear to me precisely what you're asking. If I may rephrase, are you looking for a satisfactory explanation of why $\{z: \mathrm{Im}(z)\in(-\pi,\pi)\}$ is a band of width $2\pi$?

Comment: yes! sorry about the wording :)

Comment: I mean, it is kind of obvious if you put it like that, but aren't I suppose to write in the form of something like $\psi <y<\psi +2\pi$

Comment: I don't think so, no, but if you'd like, you could write it as $-\pi<y<-\pi+2\pi$ ;)